# Removing records with blank field through a named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, named-scope

I have created a Ruby on Rails app that allows users to track workouts. I allow them to make a workout private or public which is denoted by passing integer `1` to `Workout.share`.
Now I am trying to display certain subsets of those `public_workouts`. I call all `public_workouts` through a named_scope:

```
# workouts_controller.rb
@workouts = Workout.public_workouts.all
```

...

```
# workout.rb
named_scope :public_workouts, :conditions => {:share => 1}
```

The Workout table also has a column for `rounds`. I want to limit the output of `public_workouts` to only records that have something in `workout.rounds`. Another words, if `workout.rounds` is blank then I don't want that included.
What is the best way to do this?

UPDATE:

I should have mentioned that I am using rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it should work:

```
named_scope :published, lambda { 
{ :conditions =>
  ["workouts.rounds IS NOT NULL AND workouts.share = ?", 1]
}}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, but I failed to mention that I was using rails 2.3.8, would that change the syntax?

Comment: that wouldnt but that assume that workouts.rounds is not NULL try change IS NOT NULL on <> ' ' (that should represent blanc string - but i dont try this)

Comment: Ah, actually that did work. I was trying to also apply this to another column I have that is a string. What would be needed instead of IS NOT NULL to check to see if the string is blank?

Comment: Ha, we commented at the same time. I am not sure I understand what you wrote with respect to changing this for a string column. Could you show the exact syntax?

Comment: sure (i think single quotation marks should represent empty string so <> '')... try change "workouts.rounds IS NOT NULL AND workouts.share = ?" to "workouts.rounds <> '' AND workouts.share = ?"

Comment: Actually for some reason, leaving out the <> actually worked so just `workout.rounds` is eliminating the blank records.